# Find out POI (within 2km) using latitude and longitude

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, ggmap, geocode

I have a dataset which corresponding of Zipcode along with lat and log.I want to find out list of hospital/bank(within 2km) from that latitude and longitude.

How to do it?

The Long/Lat data looks like

```
store_zip   lon lat
410710    73.8248981    18.5154681
410209    73.0907       19.0218215
400034    72.8148177    18.9724162
400001    72.836334     18.9385352
400102    72.834424     19.1418961
400066    72.8635299    19.2313448
400078    72.9327444    19.1570343
400078    72.9327444    19.1570343
400007    72.8133825    18.9618411
400050    72.8299518    19.0551695
400062    72.8426858    19.1593396
400083    72.9374227    19.1166191
400603    72.9781047    19.1834148
401107    72.8929       19.2762702
401105    72.8663173    19.3053477
400703    72.9992013    19.0793547
401209          NA          NA
401203    72.7983705    19.4166761
400612    73.0287209    19.1799265
400612    73.0287209    19.1799265
400612    73.0287209    19.1799265
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far? This seems to be an interesting Q but Without any code it might be marked as *too broad*

Comment: @loki - I am very new to R....try to find some interesting things...

## search for a specific place type
google_places(location = c(73.8248981,18.5154681),
              place_type = "Hospital",
              radius = 20000,
              key = key)

But how to define this "key" using google api in R.
I think his two links are very helpful -

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googleway/versions/2.2.0/topics/google_places
https://rpubs.com/praisons/datahoppersdcassignment2

Comment: is the `google_places` function a thing? if so, which package is it from?

Comment: I think package name is "googleway"

Comment: Do you have a valid Developers API Key? This is required for googleway? Is it necessary to use google, or might OSM work as well?

Comment: as per the doc.key is needed but my key is not working showing me access denied error...

Comment: Please add what you have tried and also error messages to the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48740574/edit) it. Thus, others are able to help you with that.

Comment: Are your Points of Interest (Hospital/Bank etc) included in your data, or are they unknown and you need to find them?

Comment: @SymbolixAU - I want to find them...list of hospitals within 2km radius w.r.t a specific lat/lon data

Comment: That's what I assumed; see my answer

Comment: @loki - the code is given below -

library("RCurl")
library("jsonlite")
library("plotGoogleMaps")
library("geosphere")
library("googleway")

key = "AIzaSyBVfsogpz3laJoCB7RpaskVIexzfvmI02I"

google_places(location = c(13.0827,80.2707),
              place_type = "hospital",
              radius = 20000,
              key = key)

$error_message
[1] "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_"

Comment: That error is telling you the API key is not valid. You need / should create your own one : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

Answer (score 5):

If your Points of Interest are unknown and you need to find them, you can use Google's API through my `googleway` package (as you've suggested in the comments). You will need a valid API key for this to work.

As the API can only accept one request at a time, you'll need to iterate over your data one row at a time. For that you can use whatever looping method you're most comforatable with

```
library(googleway) ## using v2.4.0 on CRAN

set_key("your_api_key")

lst <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){

  google_places(search_string = "Hospital", 
                location = c(df[x, 'lat'], df[x, 'lon']),
                radius = 2000)

})
```

`lst` is now a list that contains the results of the queries. For example, the names of the hospitals it has returned for the first row of your data is

```
place_name(lst[[1]])

# [1] "Jadhav Hospital"                                                
# [2] "Poona Hospital Medical Store"                                   
# [3] "Sanjeevan Hospital"                                             
# [4] "Suyash Hospital"                                                
# [5] "Mehta Hospital"                                                 
# [6] "Deenanath Mangeshkar Hospital"                                  
# [7] "Sushrut Hospital"                                               
# [8] "Deenanath Mangeshkar Hospital and Research Centre"              
# [9] "MMF Ratna Memorial Hospital"                                    
# [10] "Maharashtra Medical Foundation's Joshi Multispeciality Hospital"
# [11] "Sahyadri Hospitals"                                             
# [12] "Deendayal Memorial Hospital"                                    
# [13] "Jehangir Specialty Hospital"                                    
# [14] "Global Hospital And Research Institute"                         
# [15] "Prayag Hospital"                                                
# [16] "Apex Superspeciality Hospital"                                  
# [17] "Deoyani Multi Speciality Hospital"                              
# [18] "Shashwat Hospital"                                              
# [19] "Deccan Multispeciality Hardikar Hospital"                       
# [20] "City Hospital"
```

---

You can also view them on a map

```
set_key("map_api_key", api = "map")


## the lat/lon of the returned results are found through `place_location()`
# place_location(lst[[1]])

df_hospitals <- place_location(lst[[1]])
df_hospitals$name <- place_name(lst[[1]])

google_map() %>%
  add_circles(data = df[1, ], radius = 2000) %>%
  add_markers(data = df_hospitals, info_window = "name")
```

[image]

Note:

- Google's API is limited to 2,500 queries per key per day, unless you pay for a premium account.